# Default value for scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I want to do something like this:

```
char name[20];
printf("Enter your name: ");
scanf("Micheal%s", &name);
```

I want `Michael` to be editable at the console, and if the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> without editing anything then name is set to `Micheal`. Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

No, there's not.

"The console" and "the mouse" are not something specified by C to exist.

You need to look into libraries, such as [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) for doing things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Not editable, but maybe not too bad:

```
char name[20] = "Michael";

printf("Enter your name [default: %s]: ", name);
fflush (stdout); /* Makes the printf output appear even without a newline. */
scanf("%s", &name);
```

All caveats about scanning with `%s` into a small buffer and not testing the return value of scanf apply.